# Конвертация типов в списках LiveData

Tags: java, android, livedata

Есть это:

```
LiveData<List<A>> list1
```

Из него нужно получить это:

```
LiveData<List<B>> list2
```

Как это можно реализовать?

Пробовал использовать `Transformations.map`, но этот метод работает только с единичными объектами, а мне нужно преобразовать сразу список.

Comment: дженерики листа типизированы классами/интерфейсами А и В?

Comment: Да. А и В это 2 разных класса.

Comment: хорошо, тогда вы должны знать , какие поля класса А в какие поля класса Б должны быть скопированы , правильно я понимаю?

Comment: Это я знаю. Метод для конвертации `А` в `В` есть. Он с успехом используется для единичных объектов в `Transformations.map`. А, вот  как поступить со списками? Конечно, есть решение в лоб: создать список для B и в него через for поместить объекты B сконвертированные из А. Но, это ручная работа и она очень похожа на костыль. Возможно в LiveData есть более изящное решение?

Comment: из коробки вряд ли, но можно прикрутить функциональное решение на стримах. есть функцональный интерфейс Function , принимающий один параметр, а возвращающий другой. на его основе написать функцию, которая будет через стрим прокидывать список , мэпить его в нужный и забирать вновь созданный. один конвертер (функция) на все преобразования - не так и плохо вроде как...